# Html5 Audio stop within a second when i play in IOS [IONIC 5]

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, ionic4, html5-audio

this is really frustrating and i have an ionic app where we need to play audio and we used html5 audio to play the radio with url like this.

```
audio = new Audio();
audio.src = url;
audio.play();
```

it works on android and all ios simulators without any problem but when we use physical device it start and stopped within a second and in logs it give this error.

```
Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x282cf67c0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: 
 "Required client entitlement is missing"> {
  userInfo = {
  RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x1592432e0; requestedReason: MediaPlayback; reason: 
  MediaPlayback; flags: PreventTaskSuspend | PreventTaskThrottleDown | 
  WantsForegroundResourcePriority>;
 }
```

Weird thing is that sometime it works but i mean it happened like one or two occasions.
if anyone has any idea please help me out.
thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've just had this today too.

Comment: i couldn't use HTML5 Audio so i had to use StreamingMedia plugin for the time being.
Did you solved it?

Comment: Don't waste your time - if the StreamingMedia works, stick with it and move on.  Otherwise, I recommend looking at VideoJs. I've used that and it seems to work very well, PM me if you want a pastebin dump or something.

Comment: Does it work for live stream radio? i need your help in this

Comment: @Osaf Did you find a way to play audio in iOS app ?

Comment: @Dave Can you please let me know how to play audio using VideoJs ?

Comment: @Darshana I ended up not using VideoJs for audio in the project at that time, take a look at howler.js though - https://howlerjs.com

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the reply. Do you know whether is it possible to play audio in background using howlerjs.com ?

Comment: @Darshana I imagine you could get it working with some background task plugin to force the O/S to keep the app 'alive' but I also think apple might reject it, maybe research that.  My app (Android only) uses a native-wrapper audio player plugin I wrote, not a web player in the page itself.